# Simple sql query does not return corresponding value needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one called users, other is messages in a single mysql database.

I am trying to make a "thread" that is between 2 users by selecting the message and name, along with the sender/user id's for extra information.

Users looks similar to this:

```
_id,    Name  
1      Mike  
2      Chris  
3      Agnes  
.. ....
```

Messages is similar to this:

```
_id, sent_id, user_id, message  
1      1    2        Hello  
2      2    1        Sup  
3      3    2        Goodbye  
..    ...
```

The current Query is this:

```
SELECT users.name, messages.message, messages.user_id as user, messages.sent_id as sender  
          FROM messages, users  
          WHERE users.user_id = messages.user_id   
          AND (messages.user_id = $senderID AND messages.sent_id = $userID)  
          OR (messages.user_id = $userID AND messages.sent_id = $senderID);
```

It works, as it sends the correct messages; however, it returns all of the user names, not the ones associated with the message.

Comment: try to use a join, something like this           FROM messages JOIN users ON messages.user_id = user.user_id WHERE ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line to filter the users:

```
AND users.user_id in ($userID, $senderID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.name, messages.message, messages.user_id as user, messages.sent_id as sender
FROM messages join users
WHERE users.user_id = messages.user_id
AND (messages.user_id = $senderID AND messages.sent_id = $userID)
OR (messages.user_id = $userID AND messages.sent_id = $senderID);
```

It is untested but the essence is that you have to use "join" keyword.